How to tell GCC that it does not need to reload a value from memory after passing a pointer to a function with read-only access
Please consider the following program:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char*(*g)(const char*)
__attribute__((__access__(__read_only__, 1)))
;

char *h(const char*)
__attribute__((__access__(__read_only__, 1)))
;

// not from string.h, declared here!
char *strdup(const char*);

int main() {
    
    g f = h; // change h to strdup to see the effect
    char c[2] = "0";
    f(c);
    
    printf("%c\n", c[0]);

    return 0;
}

(godbolt.org)
What I am trying to do is to convince GCC that it does not need to load the value for c[0] from memory when calling printf().
I am also interested in a solution that works for function pointers.
Since const can easily be cast away, I was already not so surprised, that the compiler won't use this information for optimization. So I tried the access attribute. But no luck.
But imagine my surprised face when I changed g f = h to g f = strdup.
The generated code when assigning h is the following:
call    h
movsbl  14(%rsp), %esi    // loaded from memory
movl    $.LC0, %edi
xorl    %eax, %eax
call    printf

While the generated code when assigning strdup is what I would also love to see for h:
call    strdup
movl    $48, %esi    // the "0" is directly written to register
movl    $.LC0, %edi  // because here GCC recognizes that the
xorl    %eax, %eax   // content did not change
call    printf

Note, that the effect is also visible when I use the custom declaration of strdup in that file (instead the declaration from string.h).
Suddenly the compiler realized that the function call will not change the contents in c and invoked printf() directly with 0x48 instead of loading the value from memory.
It looks like there is some hard-coded optimization for strdup wired into the compiler.
Question: But how can I convince GCC to do the same optimization for my function h (and preferably also for functions called via the function pointer)?

Update: since some commenters were confused by the fact, that the example illustrated the effect with a single char instead of a proper string, I have changed the example accordingly. Additionally, I have highlighted the main question.
Update 2: copied the results of godbolt.org to the question, because not everyone wants to click the link and try it out.

You cannot call strdup() with something that is not a string. Invoke UB and the compiler will get its revenge!

@pmg good catch, but no, doesn't matter. When I change c='0' to c='\0' I'll make it a perfectly valid (empty) string, but still the same effect.

The compiler has built-in knowledge of the behavior of (some) standard library functions.

Note that f() and strdup() take a char * parameter. You are passing a char value (not a char * for the parameter of interest) to printf. Not an equivalent comparison case, a very meaningful difference. Note also that the 'movb    $48, 15(%rsp)' appears to me to be the initialization of 'c', not the setting up of the parameter for the call to f(). A relevant question that needs to be asked for this is: what cpu registers does the implementation require a function to preserve? (I don't currently know.)

"64 bit x86 C Calling Convention . . . The caller-saved registers are r10, r11, and any registers that parameters are put into. If
you want the contents of these registers to be preserved across the subroutine call, push them onto
the stack." So it appears that the compiler must assume that any registers used for passing parameters to a function have been trashed during that function call.

I have updated the question to avoid any confusion that might draw the attention away from the main topic.

The problem is not much that the compiler reload c[0], it is that it cannot store it in a register and keep the register state after the function calls. This is a contraint of the ABI (as pointed out by Avi Berger), not C or GCC. The only solution for GCC is either to know that the function does not impact all register (so by knowing the function for example which is not the case here and not possible for generic function pointers that might be compiled in another TU by another compiler), or to keep the value in a register that is known to be restored (e.g. rsp & rbp which are already used).

@JérômeRichard I see that the question was still not clear enough. I have copied the result from godbolt.org to pinpoint exactly what I mean.

@JérômeRichard Actually, I believe what the OP wants is not maintaining the register or reloading the value, but replacing either by an immediate constant value in the asm instruction, skipping the use of the variable altogether. My ABI comment is more of a side note about stuff you should be aware of when looking at things at this level. Another point the OP should know is that getting the strdup declaration via #include or typing it out are equivalent to the compilation. #include is effectively a paste operation into the file.

@AviBerger I have declared strdup on my own to illustrate that it does not matter whatever additional attributes the string.h might have appended to the declaration.

This seems to boil down to how long does the compiler's analysis track and recognize that something has a know value that can be directly used rather than sourced from the variable that contains it. The answer appears likely to be @user17732522's "compiler has built-in knowledge of the behavior of (some) standard library functions" and you can't necessarily force this compiler behavior. If you really need this, generate asm from the C, hand modify the asm and use it. (Note: built into the compiler, not derived from the contents of string.h)

It's not just gcc, when I checked clang also didn't trust that the string hasn't changed without actually seeing the code (or its guaranteed-by-the-standard behvaior).

@jthill has a good point. If the function code was visible in the translation unit before the call, it might facilitate the compiler to do more constant propagation across the call.

Ok, thank you. Note that adding static const to c does generate a mov by a constant. Yes, compilers can make assumption about the glibc (tightly bound to gcc) since it is part of the implementation. Yes, GCC can also make assumption based on the definition (and can inline the function without its definition in some cases, e.g. strlen). Here, for strdup, it is not in the same TU. Note its prototype is extern char *strdup (const char*) __attribute__((__nothrow__, __leaf__)) __attribute__((__malloc__)) __attribute__((__nonnull__(1)));. Using the same attributes for h has no impact.

@jthill Clang knows the implementation of strdup, considers it as a built-in, inlines it (enabling optimizations that are not possible otherwise) and finally completely optimize it out (no op). This is done even only with -O1. This is different from gcc which still keep the call instruction.

Have you tried to declare const c[2] = "p"; ??? I recommend not to redefine standard library functions that have been declared with lots of intrinsic attributes, and use new, clean names for that.

A better test case is to call if (c[0] != '0') printf("%c\n", c[0]);: https://godbolt.org/z/9h61YYPcc  In that case the compiler should eliminate the printf call with the knowledge that c was not modified. In the case of strdup() the compiler knows that as it is a special built-in function. But that access attribute should have told the compiler the same thing he knows about strdup() or what is the point of the attribute?

@GoswinvonBrederlow yes, that is exactly my question.

This is because the compiler recognizes strdup as a special library function case and therefore makes assumptions to inline the call based on that. Whereas your custom function has external linkage and cannot get inlined. If you provide a function definition along with guaranteed inlining, you'll see the same behavior as with strdup:
__attribute__((always_inline)) static inline char *h (const char* x)
{ 
  /* do something meaningful here */
}

With the definition visible in the same translation unit, I get the same movl $48, %esi as you did with strdup.

I think this might have to do with aliasing and that the compiler isn't allowed to assume that a function taking const char* as parameter didn't modify the data, because const char* and char[] alias.

But the solution can't be to make the definition always visible to the compiler, can it? I mean.. what good are the attributes (especially __access__) for, then. Would be quite disappointing if the answer to "how can I tell GCC to apply this optimization" is just: "you can't". :-D

Perhaps too pedantic: While inlining would be a good explanation, note that if you examine the generated code in the OP's example strdup is not being inlined. So actual inlining isn't required, but visibility of the function body and some characteristics of the body seem to be. And using an inline function is a way to get the body visible.

@UniversE Of course it can - what you are dealing with here are manual micro-optimizations, often dismissed as "premature optimization" as in the programmer focusing on improving performance when there isn't even a problem to solve. There are countless situations when compilers will not generate the most optimal code.

@AviBerger Possibly there's some side effect which can't get optimized out. The call is a no-op since the result isn't stored anywhere so I actually expect the compiler to remove it entirely. But maybe the side effect of creating a memory leak is something that can't be optimized out.

+1 for strdup being magical. But the rest is just lucky and results of it all getting optimized the way you want by accident. It's not making the access attribute suddenly work.

@lundin If you use if (c[0] != '0') printf("%c\n", c[0]); then in the strdupcase the compiler optimizes it all out. So, no, the strdup side effect of memory leaking isn't preventing anything.
